# NAudio UI volume meter

Tags: c#, .net, naudio, soundcard

Is there a way to subscribe periodics events in order to get a reduced sample from audio output?
I'd like to design a volume meter and I don't want use timers. I only need a visual feedback on my volume indicator.

Other solutions would be welcome.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OVkd6xIWHDc

Comment: I'm afraid they use timers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `MeteringSampleProvider` for this purpose. As the documentation says:

> Simple SampleProvider that passes through audio unchanged and raises
>   an event every n samples with the maximum sample value from the period
>   for metering purposes